# Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'

Tags: datatable, salesforce, visualforce

Hi I am trying to implement a data table in Visualforce page. I have included the jquery.js, DataTable.Min.Js, Datatable.js in the page in this order. I have initialize the data table like below

```
$(document).ready( function () {
          var oTable1 = $('#LeadTable').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ ] }],
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "iDisplayLength" : 20,
                "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
                "oColumnFilterWidgets": { "aiExclude": [ 0, 3, 4 ] }
           });
});
```

I am getting the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'". I check what is the issue?
Thanks.

## VF page

```
<apex:page controller="HomeBasedClass"  id="thePage" >
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.RoleHierarchyPopupStyle}"/>






    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: #f5f5f5;

        }

        #Initialloading{
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            top: 200px;
            /*left: 200px;*/
            /*position: fixed;*/
            display: block;
            z-index: 99
        }

        #loading-image{
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 45%;
            z-index: 100
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = setInterval(function () {
            clearInterval(i);

            // The desired code is only this:
            document.getElementById("Initialloading").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thePage:formId").style.display = "";

        }, 5000);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showPopUp(divId)
         {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display = '';
         }

         function ClosePopup(divId){
             document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
         }
    </script>
    <style>
        #LeadTable { border-collapse: collapse; }
        h3 {    color: #333333;
           font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
           font-size: 14px;
           line-height: 20px;
          }

       #panel table { border-collapse: collapse; }

    </style>

    <style>
        .button { background: url('{!$Resource.LoadingButton}') no-repeat left top; width:335px; height:65px;}
        .circle {

            width:22px;
            height:22px;
            float:left;   
            margin-bottom:18px; 
            margin-top:18px;
            margin-left: 55px;
        }

        .txt {
            font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:13px;
            color:#000000;
            line-height:20px;
            margin-left:15px;
            margin-bottom:18px;
            margin-top:18px; 
            width: 200px;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: left;
        }
       #TaskTable_paginate {
        height:35px;
       } 
    </style>
    <div id="Initialloading" align="center">
       <img src="{!$Resource.Loading}" />
       <br/><br/>
       <font color="Red">Please Wait...</font>
    </div>  
    <apex:form id="formId" style="display:none;">

        <!--<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->



        <!--<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jQueryLib19Compress}"/>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/js/jquery.dataTables.js')}"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/js/ColVis.js')}"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/js/ZeroClipboard.js')}"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/js/TableTools.js')}"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/js/ColumnFilterWidgets.js')}"></script>-->
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.DtJQueryJs}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.DtDataTableMinJs}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.DtDataTableJs}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables, 'media/css/DataTablesAdvancedExample.css')}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready( function () {
                var oTable1 = $('#LeadTable').dataTable( {
                      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                      "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ ] }],
                      "bLengthChange": false,
                      "bAutoWidth": false,
                      "iDisplayLength" : 20,
                      "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
                      "oColumnFilterWidgets": { "aiExclude": [ 0, 3, 4 ] }
                 });

                var oTable2 = $('#JobprofileTable').dataTable( {
                           "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                           "iDisplayLength" : 5,
                           "bLengthChange": false,
                           "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ ] }],
                           "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
                           "oColumnFilterWidgets": { "aiExclude": [ 0, 3, 4 ]}
               });


          });

          function startSplash() {
             document.getElementById('splashDiv').style.display='';
          }

          function endSplash() {            
            document.getElementById('splashDiv').style.display='none';
          }
        </script>

        <div class="button" id="splashDiv" style="display: none; position: fixed; left: 500px; top: 250px; border: 0px; z-index: 9999;">
            <div class="circle"><apex:image value="{!$Resource.LoadingImage}"></apex:image></div>
            <div class="txt">Please Wait. Loading...</div>
        </div> 
        <apex:actionStatus id="splashStatus"  onstart="startSplash();" onstop="endSplash();" />

        <apex:actionFunction name="ajaxSetClientLoaded" action="{!setClientLoaded}" immediate="true" rerender="formId"/> 
        <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Home Base - Sales Rep Dashboard"/>
        <a href="#thePage:formId:leadSection">Leads</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;|<apex:outputLabel >&nbsp; &nbsp;</apex:outputLabel><a href="#thePage:formId:jobProfileSection"><apex:outputLabel >Job Profiles</apex:outputLabel></a><apex:outputLabel >&nbsp; &nbsp;|</apex:outputLabel>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#thePage:formId:OpportunitySection">Opportunities</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#thePage:formId:TaskSection">Activities</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#thePage:formId:OrderSection">Orders &amp; Deliveries</a><br/><br/><br/>
        <label style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline" onclick="showPopUp('descreteAddDiv');">{!$UserRole.Name}</label><br/><br/>
        <div id="descreteAddDiv" style="display:none;">
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="DescAddresspopupBackground" layout="block" />
            <apex:outputPanel id="fulfillingBranchPanel" style="-moz-border-radius: 15px;-webkit-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 10px;" styleClass="custDescAddressPopup" layout="block" >
                <div style="width:25px; float:right;padding:5px 5px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="ClosePopup('descreteAddDiv');">[X]</div>
                    <apex:iframe src="/apex/testpage" width="100%" height="350px" scrolling="true"/>          
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </div>

        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Lead section Start------------------------------------------ -->
        <apex:pageBlock id="leadSection" >
            <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="8">
                 <tr>
                    <td align="left" colspan="2"><h3>Leads</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%" valign="top" height="265px;">
                        <apex:outputPanel id="componentPnl">
                            <c:LeadGraphComponent userId="{!SelectedUserId}" id="LeadComponent"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                    <td width="75%" valign="top">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="LeadTable" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                     <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt;">Company</th>
                                     <th>Name</th>
                                     <th>Phone</th>
                                     <th>Servicing Branch ID</th>
                                     <th>Created Date</th>
                                     <th>Last Activity Date</th>
                                     <th>Next Activity Date</th>
                                 </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                                 <apex:repeat value="{!LstLeadGrid}" var="c">
                                     <tr>
                                        <td><a href="https://c.cs3.visual.force.com/{!c.id}" target="_blank">{!c.Company}</a></td>
                                        <td>{!c.Name}</td>
                                        <td>{!c.Phone}</td>
                                        <td>{!c.Servicing_Branch_Id__c}</td>
                                        <td>
                                             <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                                <apex:param value="{!c.Created_Date_Time__c}"/> 
                                            </apex:outputText>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                             <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                                <apex:param value="{!c.Last_Activity_Datetime__c }" /> 
                                            </apex:outputText>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                             <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                                <apex:param value="{!c.Next_Activity_Date__c}" /> 
                                            </apex:outputText>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </apex:repeat>
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Lead section End------------------------------------------ -->
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Job Profile section Start------------------------------------>
        <!-- ------rendered="{!IF(($UserRole.Name == 'Branch Manager - US') || ($UserRole.Name == 'Customer Sales Specialist - NSC - US') || ($UserRole.Name == 'Regional Manager - US') || ($UserRole.Name == 'Sales Rep - US') || ($UserRole.Name == 'Territory Sales Mgr - US'),true,false)}"---->
        <apex:pageBlock id="jobProfileSection" >
            <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="8">
                 <tr>
                    <td align="left" colspan="2"><h3>Job Profiles</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%" valign="top" height="265px;">
                        <apex:outputPanel id="componentPnl">
                            <c:JobProfileComponent userId="{!SelectedUserId}" id="JpComponent"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" width="75%" valign="top">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="JobprofileTable" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                     <th>Job profile Name</th>
                                     <th>Job Profile ID</th>
                                     <th>BranchID</th>
                                     <th>Valuation</th>
                                     <th>GC Name</th>
                                     <th>JS City</th>
                                     <th>JS State</th>
                                     <th>Job Name</th>
                                     <th>JS Zip</th>
                                 </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                                 <apex:repeat value="{!LstJobProfileGrid}" var="c">
                                     <tr>
                                        <td align="left" style="font-colour: black;"><a href="https://c.cs3.visual.force.com/{!c.id}" target="_blank">{!c.Name}</a></td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Job_Profile_ID__c}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Branch_ID__c}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Valuation__c}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.GC_Awarded_Dodge__c}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Job_Site_City__c}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Job_Site_State__c}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Name}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{!c.Job_Site_Zip__c}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </apex:repeat>
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock> 
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Job Profile End------------------------------------------ -->
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Opportunity section Start------------------------------------------ --> 
        <apex:pageBlock id="OpportunitySection">
            <c:OpportunityComponent userId="{!SelectedUserId}" id="OppComponent"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Opportunity section End------------------------------------------ -->
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Activity section Starts------------------------------------------ -->
        <apex:pageBlock id="TaskSection">

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

                $(document).ready( function () {
                        var oTable4 = $('#TaskTable').dataTable( {
                              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                              "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ ] }],
                              "bLengthChange": false,
                              "iDisplayLength" : 20,
                              "oColumnFilterWidgets": { "aiExclude": [ 0, 3, 4 ] }
                      });
                 });

            </script>
            <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <h3>My Activities</h3> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="https://cs3.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity&retURL=%2F006%2Fo&save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F006%252Fo" style="Text-decoration:none;Cursor:pointer"><img src="https://cs3.salesforce.com/resource/1359464023000/ZoomImage" Title="Create New Opportunity"/> Create New Opportunity</a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedTaskName}" size="1" style="width:250px;">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstTaskOptions}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ChangeSelectedTaskName}" rerender="TaskSection" status="splashStatus"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="panel" >
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="TaskTable" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Subject</th>
                         <th>Due Date</th>
                         <th>MMI Call Type</th>
                         <th>Account Name</th>
                         <th>Name</th>
                         <th>Related To</th>
                         <th>Phone</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!LstTaskGrid}" var="c">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="https://c.cs3.visual.force.com/{!c.id}" target="_blank">{!c.Subject}</a></td>
                              <td style= "{!IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(c.ActivityDate)),c.ActivityDate- Today() < 0), 'color:red;', 'color:black;')}">
                                  <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                      <apex:param value="{!c.ActivityDate}" /> 
                                  </apex:outputText>
                              </td>
                              <td>{!c.Call_Type__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Account.Name}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Who.Name}</td>
                              <td>{!c.What.Name}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Who.Phone}</td>  
                          </tr>
                         </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
             </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Activity section End------------------------------------------ -->
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Order and Delivery section Starts------------------------------------------ -->
        <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;border: 1px solid #F00;" >
        <apex:pageBlock id="OrderSection">
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

                $(document).ready( function () {
                    var oTable5 = $('#OrderTable').dataTable( {
                          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                          "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ ] }],
                          "bLengthChange": false,
                          "bAutoWidth": false,
                          "iDisplayLength" : 15,
                          "oColumnFilterWidgets": { "aiExclude": [ 0, 3, 4 ] }
                     });
                 });

            </script>
            <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <h3>Orders &amp; Deliveries</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedlstOrdDelivOptionsName}" size="1" style="width:250px;">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstOrdDelivOptions}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ChangeOrderDelivery}" rerender="OrderSection" status="splashStatus"/>
                        </apex:selectList><br/><br/>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedOrdDelivTimeName}" size="1" style="width:250px;">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstOrdDelivTimeOptions}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ChangeOrderDelivery}" rerender="OrderSection" status="splashStatus"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="OrderTable" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>Account #</th>
                         <th>Account Name</th>
                         <th>Order Type</th>
                         <th>Transaction Code</th>
                         <th>Servicing Branch ID</th>
                         <th>Item Code</th>
                         <th>Total Amt</th>
                         <th>Delivery Date</th>
                         <th>Activation Date</th>
                         <th>Fuel Surcharge Delivery</th>
                         <th>Fuel Surcharage PickUp</th>
                         <th>PPE</th>
                         <th>LLW</th>
                         <th>Delivery Contact Name</th>
                         <th>Delivery Contact #</th>
                         <th>Order #</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tbody>
                      <apex:repeat value="{!LstOrdersAndDelieveriesGrid}" var="c">
                           <tr>
                              <td>{!c.Account_Number__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Name}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Transaction_Code__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Transaction_Code__c }</td>
                              <td>{!c.Transaction_Code__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Item_Code__c}</td>
                              <td>{!SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(ROUND(c.Total__c, 0)), ".", "," )}</td>
                              <td>
                                   <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                      <apex:param value="{!c.Delivery_Date__c}"/> 
                                  </apex:outputText>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                   <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                      <apex:param value="{!c.Activation_Date__c}"/> 
                                  </apex:outputText>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                      <apex:param value="{!c.Fuel_Surcharge_Delivery__c}"/> 
                                </apex:outputText>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                      <apex:param value="{!c.Fuel_Surcharage_PickUp__c}"/> 
                                </apex:outputText>

                              </td>
                              <td>{!c.PPE__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.LLW__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Delivery_Contact_Name__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Delivery_Contact_Number__c}</td>
                              <td>{!c.Order_Number__c}</td>
                          </tr>
                      </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
       </apex:pageBlock>
       </div>
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------Order and Delivery section End------------------------------------------ -->
    </apex:form>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        /*#OrderTable_wrapper {width:100%; overflow:auto;}*/
    </style>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: @Pavel I have added the code in my question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

seems that you should to use the following fix:

```
 var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

The problem is that force.com also includes a lot of javascript libraries that also may use this $ symbol as a shortcut and this can cause all sorts of problems. 
Now where ever you would normally use $, use j$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I am getting error like "j$().dataTable is not a function"